What is the equivalent of Array(N).keys().map for Apple products (Safari/iPhones)?
I'm trying to get a list of incremental numbers from N to (N + M) and using Array(M).keys().map(num => num + N) to do so. This works fine on:

Windows Chrome
Windows Edge
Mac Chrome

But I receive a TypeError: Arror(3).keys().map is not a function error on:

iPhone Chrome, Safari, and the Inspect Browser app.
Mac Safari

Why is it not defined, and what would be an equivalent call?
In the console, Array(n).keys() produces a Array Iterator which holds the array prototype (which defines map), so I'm confused what's happening on certain Apple products.

This has only very recently become available in other browsers and it's not yet in the standard. So, it's not Safari which is the odd one out, it's everything else for supporting iterator helpers early.

Are you searching for a way to get an iterable? Or do you just want to create an array with ascending numbers?

Thanks for more context VLAZ. That makes sense. I also found a way to achieve what I wanted by wrapping the keys result into an Array using Array.from(...). Posted an answer.

OK, then this is a duplicate.

To answer part of my own question, wrapping Array(N).keys() with Array.from(...) solves the issue by returning an array, rather than an iterator, which you can then call .map on.
From VLAZ's response, it seems that some browsers only recently added support for map on an Array Iterator.
